# Communicate between embedded lightning component and the standard page layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

In Lightning Experience, is it possible for an embedded lightning component to transfer data to the lightning page that its embedded in?

e.g. Embedded component performs a search of some records, user selects one of the results and the selected result is then copied into a custom field on the lightning page (without having to save & refresh the page).

Comment: It's possible if your Lightning Component is only linked to one record, which is the one shown in the Lighting page. Using a [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordData.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding you completely, Some screenshots or code samples would help, but I'll take a swing.

Assuming both components are yours (custom)

You'll want to have a look at [communicating with events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_events.htm). The best scenario would be for the search component to be a child or sibling component to your textbox cmp. Then you could communicate directly with component events.

If you not, you can use application events, but there are some nuances there with navigation and caching in the LEX so I would avoid it.

There are [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_events) on this a well

Comment: I'm not trying to communicate between 2 components on a page, i'm trying to get an embedded component to update a field on the standard lightning page layout based on some action (without having to save & refresh the page) i.e.e just push some data to a field

Comment: In that case the short answer is no. Custom you could do it with some creativty. You could replace the standard layouts with custom components leveraging the force:recordView which can take an ID or (as you want in this case) a full Record. You'd have your components communicate and update the backing v.record prop.